# Mathematical Equations Puzzle: Perfect Sixes

Tags: code-review, puzzle, recreational-mathematics

pI have given the following problem to my students

Write some code that solves the perfect sixes problem for all numbers it works for!

The perfect sixes problem asks you to solve some equations:
\begin{align}
0 \quad  0 \quad 0 &= 6\\
1\quad  1\quad  1 &= 6\\
2\quad  2\quad  2 &= 6\\
3 \quad 3\quad  3 &= 6\\
4 \quad 4 \quad 4 &= 6\\
5\quad  5 \quad 5 &= 6\\
6 \quad 6 \quad 6 &= 6\\
7 \quad 7 \quad 7 &= 6\\
8\quad  8 \quad 8 &= 6\\
9 \quad 9 \quad 9 &= 6\\
10\quad  10\quad  10 &= 6\\
\end{align}

You can do any math operations to these numbers: add, subtract, multiply, divide, square, cube, log, factorial, etc.

You need to use exactly the numbers in the equation (you can't only use two of the 3s, and you can't use four 3s).

The goal is to make each equation correct.

You do have to follow the order of operations rules. You can use () to accomplish this. Math is math!

For example:

```
Subtract[Times[3, 3], 3]
```

I gave the an example from 0-100
***Solution***

```
Print[Factorial[1 + 1 + 1] == 6]
Print[2*2 + 2 == 6]
Print[3*3 - 3 == 6]
Print[4 + 4 - Sqrt[4] == 6]
Print[5/5 + 5 == 6]
Print[6 - 6 + 6 == 6]
Print[7 - 7/7 == 6]
Print[CubeRoot[8] + CubeRoot[8] + CubeRoot[8] == 6]
Print[(9 + 9)/Sqrt[9] == 6]
Print[(Sqrt[(10 - 10/10)])! == 6]
```

***Then I asked them the following***

Find all the numbers 1 - 100 where you can make 6 out of three of them. Eg . 100, 100, 100.

Then one of them used the following code

```
x = Range[100]
Factorial[Factorial[x^0] + Factorial[x^0] + Factorial[x^0]] == 6
```

Could I accept this answer as correct?

Comment: What for? Isn't it art for art's sake?

Comment: @user64494 he wanted to know if his answer is correct

Comment: Just stating what you already know: As the range is 1 to 100 the inner factorials are unnecessary and of course (1+1+1)! =6. It is generalization of  (0!+0!+0!)! solution  but seems counter  to the puzzle rules by allowing Power[x, 0] .  However, that is teacher call.